# How to get absolute website URL in Json call function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, javascript-framework, unobtrusive-javascript

I called below function on page load.

```
http://www.test.com/home
http://biz.test.com/abhishek/favorites
http://www.test.com/chat/messages
http://prod.test.com/conversation
```

I want to get absolute website path in javascript,
so I easily assign below variable **strLink** 
here I assign fixed path **strLink= "www.test.com";**  instead I want it dynamic.
How can I get website url path..

suppose my url ->

```
http://prod.test.com/conversation
```

**I want** `http://prod.test.com/` not full path..

```
  var strLink ;
    strLink= "www.test.com"; // <- here I want to add dynamic path..
    strLink = strLink + "Service/getnames.asmx/GetNameByCity"
    function getName() {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: strLink,
            data: "{}",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function(msg) {
                 // code
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: What is your question? What goes wrong? Can you make an example?

Comment: Are you getting a success response from the ajax call? If so, what is returned in msg? You can debug with something like Firebug more easily.

Comment: @Pekka I edited.. please look into this.

Comment: Aah, so you want to find out the current domain your script is on? But why not just use `/Service/getnames.asmx/GetNameByCity`?

Comment: @Pekka Thanks , but I tried that but service method was not called. so I try another ans..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the URL of the current webpage, you can use the [`location`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.location) object.

In this case, you need the `location.protocol` and `location.hostname`:

```
url: location.protocol + '//' + location.hostname + '/Service/getnames.asmx/GetNameByCity',
```

Answer (score 1):

@lonesomeday is entirely correct about how to find out the current protocol and domain. However in this case, you won't need the domain name at all. Just specify a root absolute path:

```
url: "/Service/getnames.asmx/GetNameByCity"
```

the starting `/` will always point to the current domain's root directory.

Comment: When I used "/" then it can not called web method.

Comment: @Abhiskek I very much doubt that. This should work as well as a URL that contains `location.hostname`

Answer (score 0):

use `window.location.hostname`